# Can Google App Engine use a third party SMTP server?

Tags: google-app-engine, smtp, cloud

Google App Engine currently limits you to 2,000 emails per day (for free) via their API.

I am trying to find a definitive answer if it is possible to use a third-party system if you need to send more.  I know that they disallow raw sockets, so I would assume that there might be trouble with this approach... but surely I'm not the first to see it.

Worst case, I can build a simple offsite web service that my GAE can call... but I'd much rather just be able to send directly through an SMTP server.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to just enable billing? Your time spent writing this workaround has a cost, too.

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  You're right - at the time I had written this, I was not aware that enabling billing gave me additional emails.  I had been away from GAE for several months, and could have sworn that that number couldn't move from 2,000 at that point.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

You're correct: you cannot make raw socket requests, nor any other direct outbound requests except through the urlfetch API. To talk to an external SMTP server, you would need to use a webservice as a proxy.

Comment: Drew is correct.  You might be able to find some other existing services too.  Perhaps something like Cake (http://www.cakemail.com/) [no affiliation] would fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

We use the [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) mail outsourcing service via the [hutools.postmark API](http://hudora.github.com/huTools/overview.html#module-huTools.postmark). Since the communication is HTTP based, it works like a charm on Google AppEngine. This might be an option for you, although it is also a for-pay service. We use it to get arround GAEs sender restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used third party providers for email services with Google App Engine.  I've used both [SendGrid](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid) and [MailGun](http://www.mailgun.com/) using their HTTP-API.