# External SMTP Server/Service with Google Apps Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, email, smtp

I have a simple Google Apps Engine app that sends an email, but I don't want to use the GAE SMTP gateway, I want to use an external gateway.  If I can't specify my gateway explicitly (i.e., smtp.myservice.com:587), I can settle for an SMTP Proxy relay over JSON or CURL.  As of 2010, this wasn't possible. ([Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000748/can-google-app-engine-use-a-third-party-smtp-server)).

Does anyone have an update on whether or not GAE, or any of the web frameworks GAE supports, exposes an external SMTP gateway/server?  If not, is there an SMTP Proxy Relay service out there that I can use to get the email to my SMTP gateway?

Answer (score 0):

App Engine apps cannot create arbitrary outgoing socket connections, which is why they can't send mail directly to an SMTP server. That was true in 2010, and it's still true today.

I'm not aware of any HTTP->SMTP gateways out there. Running a service is problematic, since you have to worry about spammers; it's unlikely you'd find a reliable service that's any cheaper or easier to use than App Engine's email solution.

If you really don't want to use App Engine's mail sending service, your best option is probably to spin up your own private-use gateway and send your email with that.